# Django annotate count of subquery items - ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate, django-aggregation

I have an Agent, Client and Car models.

In Client model: `agent = ForeignKey('Agent'...)`

In Car model: `client = ForeignKey('Client'...)`

I want to annotate (on an Agent QuerySet) a total number of active cars of all clients of an agent.

So if the agent Bob has clients Alice and Peter, Alice has 3 active cars and Peter has 2 active cars, the `active_cars` variable will be 5.

I tried:

```
Agent.objects.annotate(
    active_cars=Subquery(
        Car.objects.all().active().filter(
            client__agent=OuterRef('pk')
        ).count()
    )
)
```

which raises:

```
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Please show the `active()` method on your `Car` queryset/manager and the related field on the model

Answer (score 1):

`.count()` does not return a queryset: it executes the queryset. That is why Django complains.

I have no idea what `.active()` does, but if just ignoring this, you can have

```
Agent.objects.annotate(
    active_cars=Count('client__car__id')
)
```

No need of a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Car` model has a boolean field named "active" and that is what you want to filter the count by, you can pass a `filter` argument to `Count` to filter the rows that are counted

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Agent.objects.annotate(
    active_cars=Count('client__car', filter=Q(client__car__active=True))
)
```

Comment: Thanks but no, `active` is a QuerySet method. I'd like to use it to keep DRY if possible.